# Object structure for creating a "wizard" form view in iOS with multiple input views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oop, wizard

I would like to use a single `WizardViewController` with different `inputView` subviews. The `WizardViewController` would share a `searchCriteria` and pass it along to each new step, with each step adding to the criteria depending on the input for that particular `inputView`.

The problem I am facing is how to structure my objects/views so that I can reuse `WizardViewController` accepting different types of input/controls. For example, I've thought of using a `WizardViewModel` that had members like `enum wizardViewModelType` (for each type of view), `UIView *inputView` that corresponds to each type of `WizardViewModelType`, and creating custom `UIView` subclasses that correspond to the different possible `inputView`s that would be needed, connecting outlets as necessary in Interface Builder. The problem is that I believe that going down this road will lead to a lot of inter-class dependencies and basically defeat the purpose of separating the `inputView` logic from the `WizardViewController`. Furthermore some of the `inputView` will require me to grab possible values from a web service, which is something that the `ViewModel` will have to handle, further breaking the logic. Perhaps I need separate `ViewController` for each type of input view? Or am I thinking about this in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the right way to do it is by having a ViewController for each UIView. The logic of your application should not be on the view, but on the viewController, and you can share data by using segues (if on ios 5), and I'm sure that there are other methods for ios 4 or below.

If I wanted to share codes between the UIViewControllers, the way I would do to make a wizard is to embedded it in a navigation controller and push the next viewController on the navigation controller stack.

If you want to share code between view controllers, I don't think you should do it on the view controller class. Basically, I would think of two options to do that:

1) write a base class: the base class should extend the UIViewController and your UIViewControllers could extend this base class.

2) extract the common code into another class (better, if applicable): You create another class that share the common code, and inject it into your view controllers.